# Autoformat for Perl in Vim

Tags: vim, perl, indentation, autoindent

I've got a piece of badly formatted Perl code:

```
if ($a==1){
   &err_report("$a");
while($b!=1){
                      &err_ok();
}
}
```

I want to **reformat** it in Vim. After using the command `gg=G`, the code is formatted as:

```
if ($a==1){
&err_report("$a");
while($b!=1){
&err_ok();
}
}
```

Actually, I want to format it in Vim as below:

```
if ($a==1){
  &err_report("$a");
  while($b!=1){
    &err_ok();
  }
}
```

What should I do?

---

- After using [vim-perl](https://github.com/vim-perl/vim-perl), the auto-formating still doesn't do what I want.

Comment: vim is good in syntax highlight, but very bad in autoformat. Maybe somebody will be able to say some useful. Until then, +1.

Comment: @PeterHorvath Maybe there some tools can connect with vim, and make vim powerful... :)

Comment: @Marslo works for me. Do you have `filetype plugin indent on` in your vimrc and does `set ft?` return `filetype=perl`?

Comment: Hi @FDinoff, [This is my vimrc](https://github.com/Marslo/VimConfig/blob/master/Configurations/vimrc), the `filetype plugin indent on` has been set at [line 110](https://github.com/Marslo/VimConfig/blob/master/Configurations/vimrc#L110). Have you added some plugin for perl syntax?

Comment: @Marslo No. I can replicate the behavior with `vim -u NONE -N a.pl -c 'filetype plugin indent on' -c 'filetype detect'` which means its not my vim configuration. I'm running vim 7.4.258.

Comment: @FDinoff, Oh yeah!!! You are right!! I think the problem might be caused by the plugins....

Comment: Well.. I found `gg=G` works for `vim -u NONE -N a.pl` ALSO! Without any setting for plugin, indent, filetype...

Answer (score 6):

*Assuming you're on a Unix-like operating system...*

Get hold of [*perltidy*](http://perltidy.sourceforge.net) (a highly customizable Perl code indenter/formatter). Then update your `~/.vimrc` file to include the following:

```
filetype plugin indent on
autocmd FileType perl setlocal equalprg=perltidy\ -st
```

This will allow you to mark whatever block of Perl code you want and then reformat it by pressing <kbd>=</kbd>. This assumes that `perltidy` is found in your `$PATH`, otherwise just specify the full path to the executable.

By default, `perltidy` will format your code as

```
if ( $a == 1 ) {
    &err_report("$a");
    while ( $b != 1 ) {
        &err_ok();
    }
}
```

... but by using `-i=2` (`--indent-columns=2`) and `-pt=2` (`--paren-tightness=2`) (you would put these options in your `~/.perltidyrc` file, one per line) you get

```
if ($a == 1) {
  &err_report("$a");
  while ($b != 1) {
    &err_ok();
  }
}
```

This is pretty much what you asked for.

If you really must have no space after `while`, ever, use `-nsak=while` (`--nospace-after-keyword=while`).

Answer (score 0):

First set the required formatting options, e.g., `set cindent sw=2 expandtab` (use C-like indentation, indent 2 spaces, expand tab character to spaces). Then indent the whole file/buffer.

Answer (score 0):

Vim comes with a Perl indent plugin, and as long as you have `:filetype indent on` somewhere in your startup (such as your vimrc) it should be able to do indenting of Perl files for you.  But note that it will only do indenting, it won't add or remove newlines.